# Confidence intervals in a line chart

Tags: logistic, confidence-interval, multiple-comparisons

Below is a random image of a line representing the probability of being satisfied as a function of household income with 95% confidence intervals for each point. The graph is ploted with `marginsplot` in Stata after a logit regression. 
[image: graph of predicted satisfactions by decile with confidence bands for each decile]

I was wondering if one can say anything about the statistically significant difference between the points on the line from this graph. Meaning, if for example I can say by only looking at this graph how the pr(satisfaction) is different at 3rd decile of the income as compared with 4th? (just by looking at this graph and the provided confidence intervals).

If yes, can you explain based on what criteria we can make such claims?

PS. The image is just taken from the internet, so, the y-axis is in fact representing scores of satisfaction. But I would not think that can change the interpretation of the points and CI.

Comment: You might find this paper useful: [Error bars in experimental biology](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2064100/)

Comment: The degree of intersection of CIs can only intuitively indicate the degree of significance of the difference between means (proportions). To state the significance directly one needs a CI for the difference in means compared to a critical value (zero or other).

Comment: @AlexeyBurnakov Do you mean we can say if the CIs of two points have relatively large overlaps, drawing horizontal lines, we can INTUITIVELY say that perhaps they are not significantly different from each other. So, while the slope of the line (beta) is significant, average outcomes between the points are not significantly different from each other. Correct? (I understand that this is just an intuitive interpretation and needs to be tested with pairwise comparisons of the points).

Comment: @Lena, Overlapping may indicate non-significance, but you cannot be sure until you take CI of the difference between means.

Comment: @AlexeyBurnakov Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your y-axis is not actually a probability, it's a self reported score. You've fit a linear model and constructed 95% CIs using a normal probability model for the mean response. It's moot to make specific pairwise comparisons between household income-deciles. The most meaningful summary of the data is the slope of the trendline, an expected difference in satisfaction comparing households differing by one decile of wealth. Might I suggest further that, instead of needlessly converting wealth to deciles, use the raw value and something more flexible than a straightline, like a spline? You usually see (at least) one inflection point in these kinds of "satisfaction versus money" questionnaires.

Comment: Thank you very much. However, I am wondering about one thing, regardless of the model specification. In such a graph above, can we say if the CIs of two points have relatively large overlaps, we can INTUITIVELY say that perhaps they are not significantly different from each other. So, while the slope of the line (beta) is significant, average outcomes between the points are not significantly different from each other. Correct? (I understand that this is just an intuitive interpretation and needs to be tested with pairwise comparisons of the points).

Comment: @Lena in general, no. "Overlapping CIs" needs be defined. Symmetric intervals (-1, 1) and (0.5, 1.5) "overlap" but might exclude the null hypothesis. Supposing the mutual intervals *contain the respective point estimates* (even non-symmetric), still we can say very little. It depends on the *estimate* and the *interval* being unbiased. Your linear model here is probably biased, I wouldn't trust the results. Go ahead and fit decile as a factor to convince yourself.

Comment: This is not a model I am estimating, this is just a random image taken from internet. But based on a similar image I heard discussions of the differences between the the points. So can it be that, for sake of simplicity you assume this model is not biased or misspecified, then the CI of the 6th decile doesn't intersect the CI of the point in the highest decile (if we draw a horizontal line), therefore we can say perhaps they are significantly different from each other?